# [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "es+??+React+js-undefined" (typ e string) at path "_id" for model "Post"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to do search and filtering in node js, but in my source code I get this url undefined in in my application:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCszh.png)

This is my file SearchController.js:

```
const Post = require("../model/Post");


const getSearchResults = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
  
    const { q } = req.query;
    const posts = await Post.find({ 'title': { $regex: q, $options: 'i' } , 'body': { $regex:1,$options:'i'} })
    .populate("author")
  
  
    if (posts.length < 1) res.status(401).json({ message: 'چیزی پیدا نشد' });

    res.status(201).json({
      status: 'success',
      message: 'Product has been found successfully',
      posts,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
  };


  module.exports = {
   
    getSearchResults
  };
```

and here is my another file from source code maybe it gives a lead how my application works

```
const Post = require("../model/Post");
const User = require("../model/User");
const Tag = require("../model/Tag");
const Comment = require("../model/Comment");
const cloudinary = require("../config/cloudinary");
const { uploadToCloudinary } = require("../utils/cloudinary");
const { getPostParams, unCapitalizeFirstLetter } = require("../helpers/string");
const { createTags, updateTags, deleteTags } = require("./tagsController");
const {
  likeNotification,
  removeLikeNotification,
  postNotification,
  removePostNotification,
} = require("./notificationsController");

const createPost = async (req, res) => {
  const { title, file, tags, body, authorUsername } = req.body;

  let urlData = {};
  if (file) {
    urlData = await uploadToCloudinary(file, { timeout: 180000 }, "Posts");
  }
  const { url, public_id: publicId } = urlData || {
    url: null,
    public_id: null,
  }; // asigns default
  // const { url, public_id: publicId } = await uploadToCloudinary(file, 'Posts');
  const author = await User.findOne({ username: authorUsername }).exec();

  const formattedTags = tags
    .trim()
    .split(",")
    .map((w) => w.trim().replace(/ /g, "-"));

  const createdPost = await Post.create({
    title,
    image: { url, publicId },
    body,
    author: author._id,
  });

  author.followers.map((followerId) => {
    (async () => {
      await postNotification(author._id, createdPost._id, followerId);
    })();
  });

  await createTags(formattedTags, createdPost);

  author.posts.push(createdPost._id);

  await author.save();

  res.status(200).json(createdPost.toObject({ getters: true }));
};

  const getPost = async (req, res) => {
    const author = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }).exec();
    const authorId = await author?.toObject({ getters: true }).id;
    const { postTitle, postId } = getPostParams(req.params.postUrl);

    const foundPost = await Post.findOne({
      author: authorId,
      title: postTitle,
      _id: postId,
    })
      .populate("author")
      .populate("comments")
      .populate("tags")
      .exec();

    res.status(200).json(foundPost?.toObject({ getters: true }));
  };



const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.params;
  const limitValue = req.query.limit || 10000;
  const skipValue = req.query.skip  ||  0;
 
 

  const posts = await Post.find(userId ? { bookmarks: userId } : {})
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .populate("author")
    .populate("tags")
    .skip(skipValue) 
     .limit(limitValue)


  if (!posts) res.status(204).json("No posts found");
  else {
    res.status(200).json(posts.map((post) => post.toObject({ getters: true })));
  }
};

const updatePost = async (req, res) => {
  const authorId = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }).exec();

  const { postTitle, postId } = getPostParams(req.params.postUrl);
  try {
    req.body.image = { url, publicId };
    const { url, public_id: publicId } = await uploadToCloudinary(
      req.body.image.url,
      "Posts"
    );
    await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(req.body.image.publicId);
  } catch (error) {}

  const formattedTags = req.body.tags
    .trim()
    .split(",")
    .map((w) => w.trim().replace(/ /g, "-"));

  const post = await Post.findOne({
    author: authorId,
    title: postTitle,
    _id: postId,
  })
    .populate("author")
    .populate("tags");

  Object.keys(req.body).map((key) => {
    if (key !== "tags") post[key] = req.body[key];
  });

  await updateTags(formattedTags, post);

  await post.save();

  res.status(200).json(post?.toObject({ getters: true }));
};

const deletePostsByUserId = async (user) => {
  const { _id: userId } = user;

  user.comments.forEach((commentId) => {
    (async () => {
      await Post.updateMany(
        { comments: commentId },
        { $pull: { comments: commentId } }
      );
    })();
  });

  const posts = await Post.find({ author: userId }).populate("tags");

  ["likes", "unicorns", "bookmarks"].forEach((k) => {
    (async () => {
      await Post.updateMany({ [k]: userId }, { $pull: { [k]: userId } });
    })();
  });

  posts.forEach((post) => {
    (async () => {
      await deleteTags(
        post.tags.map(({ name }) => name),
        post,
        true
      );
      
      await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(post.image.publicId);
      await Post.deleteOne({ _id: post._id });
    })();
  });

  await Comment.deleteMany({ author: userId });
};

const deletePost = async (req, res) => {
  const {  file } = req.body;

  const author = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }).exec();
  const { postTitle, postId } = getPostParams(req.params.postUrl);
let url={};
if (file) {  
  
   url = await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(req.body.publicId);
}

  const foundPost = await Post.findOne({
    author: author._id,
    title: postTitle,
    _id: postId,
  })
    .populate("tags")
    .exec();

  if (!foundPost) return res.sendStatus(204);

  const comments = await Comment.find({ parentPost: postId }).populate({
    path: "author",
    populate: "followers",
  });

  comments.forEach(({ author }) =>
    (async () => {
      author.comments.forEach((comment) => author.comments.pull(comment));
    })()
  );
  author.posts.pull(postId);
  await author.save();

  await Comment.deleteMany({ parentPost: postId });

  await deleteTags(
    foundPost.tags.map(({ name }) => name),
    foundPost,
    true
  );

  removePostNotification(author._id, foundPost._id, author.followers);

  await Post.deleteOne({ _id: foundPost._id });

  res.status(200).json(foundPost.toObject({ getters: true }));
};

const postReaction = async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.body;
  const { action, postUrl } = req.params;
  const { postTitle, postId } = getPostParams(postUrl);
  const isUndoing = action.includes("remove");
  const actionKey = isUndoing
    ? unCapitalizeFirstLetter(action.replace("remove", "")) + "s"
    : action + "s";

  const author = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }).exec();
  const authorId = await author.toObject({ getters: true }).id;

  const updatedPost = await Post.findOneAndUpdate(
    { author: authorId, title: postTitle, _id: postId },
    isUndoing
      ? { $pull: { [actionKey]: userId } }
      : { $addToSet: { [actionKey]: userId } },
    { new: true, timestamps: false }
  );

  if (isUndoing)
    await removeLikeNotification(userId, updatedPost._id, authorId);
  else await likeNotification(userId, updatedPost._id, authorId);

  res.status(200).json(updatedPost.toObject({ getters: true }));
};

module.exports = {
  createPost,
  getPosts,
  getPost,
  updatePost,
  deletePost,
  deletePostsByUserId,
  postReaction,
};
```

I used .populate tags . but it did not work - why am I getting this "undefined" in url ?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).